Typing in Overleaf editor is laggy on Safari
I recently switched from using Chrome to Safari on my laptop. I frequently use Overleaf to write LaTeX documents. In Chrome, I never experienced lag while typing in the Overleaf editor. However, in Safari, I constantly have a little bit of lag while typing in the Overleaf editor. The lag is persistent independent of the Overleaf document I am working on (even a blank document!). The lag also seems to go away if I zoom out of the compiled Overleaf document.
What is the cause of this laggy typing? Is there a way to resolve this issue?

welcome! this really doesn't have anything to do with TeX. it's to do with the overleaf editor and safari versus chrome. so I'd recommend you ask overleaf in the first instance. failing that, a mac forum might be the most relevant place to ask. it isn't going to be caused by anything in the tex stack.
